# Spring snake case and validation error response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using snake case for the json mapping of my API build with spring boot. spring allows you to define this easily in the application.properties file with:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

This works fine. But if i add validation and i try to post an invalid json body the response message contains the missing field in camel case. Here are my controller and the transfer object:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class MyObject {
    @NotNull
    String camelCasedField;

    public MyObject() {}

    public String getCamelCasedField() {
        return camelCasedField;
    }

    public void setCamelCasedField(String camelCasedField) {
        this.camelCasedField = camelCasedField;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class MyController {    
    @PostMapping
    public void createTenant(@RequestBody @Valid MyObject myObject) {}
}
```

If i post the following json body everything is fine:
_
    { "camel_cased_field": "test" }

If i post an empty json body i get expected error but the field name is camel case instead of snake case:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-23T07:43:18.987+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotNull.myObject.camelCasedField",
                "NotNull.camelCasedField",
                "NotNull.java.lang.String",
                "NotNull"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "myObject.camelCasedField",
                        "camelCasedField"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "default_message": "camelCasedField",
                    "code": "camelCasedField"
                }
            ],
            "default_message": "must not be null",
            "object_name": "myObject",
            "field": "camelCasedField", // should be camel_cased_field
            "rejected_value": null,
            "binding_failure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='myObject'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/api/test"
}
```

Is there a way to fix this for all endpoints of a spring application?

Comment: I think its camel case because it contains the **java filed name of the java class**, not the json field name missing in the request...

Comment: Yes sure, but that is exactly the problem. it should contain the json field not the java field name.

Comment: Then you probably need a different error handler, maybe your own..., but I don't know anything more about it...

Comment: Is the error response custom created by you? Check if your application is using a new instance of jackson ObjectMapper for error handling. Also check if you are using webflux.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `javax.validation` framework will use the Bean field casing, which is typically camel casing for Java Bean fields.

But there is a way to change that. Not an easy way, but there is a way.

- Define a `RestControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions in your project. (this is normally a part of most spring apps)
- Add a handler for the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` and `ConstraintViolationException` exceptions. One is used for POST body violations and the other for path/query string validation violations.
- `MethodArgumentNotValidException` exposes a `BindingResult` field, which has a list of `FieldError` objects, and each field error object has a field called "`field`". You need to use reflection to set the value of this field from camel casing to whatever casing you want.
- Similarly, `ConstraintViolationException` exposes a field called "`propertyPath`" that you can manipulate.

Please note that, you can avoid reflection and a lot of pain, if you don't emit the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` as-is in your http 400 response. Normally, folks handle this exception and extract out the field name and message, and then just emit those messages as a list, in the http 400 (or 422 :)) response. If you do that, then it is a matter of transforming the field-names, and not messing with the private value inside the `FieldError` object.

Here is a sample:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionResolver {

  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
  public ErrorResponse handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(HttpServletRequest request,
                 MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

    final List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    final BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

      final List<FieldError> fieldErrorList = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();

      for (FieldError fieldError : fieldErrorList) {
        String kebabFieldName = YOUR_METHOD_TO_CONVERT_CAMEL_TO_KEBAB(fieldError.getField());
        // use kebabFieldName and message to construct your response.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An example of YOUR_METHOD_TO_CONVERT_CAMEL_TO_KEBAB is this, if you use google-guava helper jar.

```
String kebab = com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL
                    .to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, fieldError.getField());
```

Let me know if you find a simpler way! Cheers.